# using Python 3 with AWS lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

Can one use application built with Python3 in lambda, and not just python2.7. Possibly looking at options around - https://gun.io/blog/announcing-zappa-serverless-python-aws-lambda/

AWS lambda documentation mentions about python2.7.

Is there some example code which I could try for python3.0 with lambda

Comment: @MarkB if that's the case, why is it im testing in lambda and getting syntax errors when i use print method without parentheses

Answer (score 32):

Lambda functions run in a container on a [well-known AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html). While you must handle the initial event with Python2.7, you can call out to anything installed on the AMI. In particular, Python3 is already installed. It's a bit complicated, but you can establish a virtualenv to take advantage of the installed python3.

For a few of the details, see http://www.cloudtrek.com.au/blog/running-python-3-on-aws-lambda/.

Edit: that link went dead. Try https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/running-python-3-aws-lambda-lyndon-swan.

Comment: The linked to URL is dead.

Answer (score 8):

Python 3.6 is now available in Ohio! (us-east-2)

I ran:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return sys.version
```

And it kicked back:

```
"3.6.1 (default, Mar 27 2017, 23:56:45) \n[GCC 4.9.3]"
```

Answer (score 4):

Python 3.6 is now fully supported by Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python 3 with aws lambda. 
when you are creating an Aws lambda function there is an option where you can use a `python 3` as a version and execute your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change runtime language to python version 3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

Answer (score 0):

You could run a lambda function in python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9

[image]

Here you have a sample code to run:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html