# AWS Lambda support for python 3.4 and cronjobs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda

I´ve created a set up using python 3.4 code (as I need the library pyrebase) as well as using Cronjobs.

AWS Lambda would do the job perfect if it wasn´t for the lack of Python 3-support.

Any ideas of other AWS computer services supporting Python and Cronjobs? (or other cloud computing services that would support the project?)

Comment: What? What do you mean by AWS not supporting Python 3?

Comment: Sorry. Ment AWS Lambda is not supporting Python 3

Comment: Indeed, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html says that only Python 2.7 supported. Time for a writeup, would be pretty trivial to support latest Python 3 if they already support 2.7.

Comment: True. They wrote in July that "Our Lambda Development Team are working towards support for Python 3.5 however we do not have an expected release date for this year." (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=728429&#728429) but that does´t help me now :-)

Comment: An EC2 instance running whatever linux flavor you want can, of course, do this.  Maybe use an AWS Lambda function to start the instance, then have the instance shut down after it's done, if you don't want/need the instance 24/7.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The environment that Lambda runs your scripts in has Python 3 available to it, so it is possible to run Python 3 code via Lambda, but it takes a bit of work (I've not done it myself).  Here's a similar question: [using Python 3 with AWS lamba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143563/using-python-3-with-aws-lamba)

And the a link from the answer in that question with some good info: http://www.cloudtrek.com.au/blog/running-python-3-on-aws-lambda/

Basically you'd have a small chunk of Python 2.7 code with the lambda handler function, which then creates a Python 3 virtualenv in which to run your Python 3 code.

As for cronjobs, you could probably put something together with timers in SWS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-timers.html .  If it has to be literal cronjobs (vs. running something on a schedule, regardless of method), you'd need an EC2 instance running cron and calling out to other services.